# Binance Spot Test Network. Error when trying to reach Testnet account balances

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, binance, cryptocurrency, binance-api-client

I am trying to test a bot on the Spot Test Network but when I try to do `acc = client.get_account()` to access some account info that is needed it raises the following error `APIError(code=-2015): Invalid API-key, IP, or permissions for action.` I have tried finding a solution but can't find anything besides a step i dindn't do from the tutorial on the [Binance Spot Test Network](https://www.binance.com/es/amp/support/faq/ab78f9a1b8824cf0a106b4229c76496d)

the step says:

Follow the official Spot API Key documentation to replace the API endpoint URLs with the following values:

https://api.binance.com/api --> https://testnet.binance.vision/api

wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws --> wss://testnet.binance.vision/ws

wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream --> wss://testnet.binance.vision/stream

When I look in the documentation I cant find anything that would help with this problem.
I am not sure this is the solution but it is the only thing I could find on it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In case you are using the `python-binance` library, see the documentation here for switching to the **Testnet**:

https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#using-the-spot-futures-or-vanilla-options-testnet

Answer (score 2):

Have you changed the baseurl to the testnet. If the `client` is still sending request to production, you will get this error even with testnet API key. Because the production server can't find it.

You should specify the testnet when initialising the `client` instance.

- https://dev.binance.vision/t/binance-testnet-environments/99
- https://dev.binance.vision/t/why-do-i-see-this-error-invalid-api-key-ip-or-permissions-for-action/93